# xQuery single XMLNode in XMLNodes collection

Tags: xml, xquery

I have a XML file that contains node named `Standplaatsen`.
I can get a collection of these nodes. Then I want to drill it into this collection with a `foreach` loop and check each seperate nodes within the node collection.

```
foreach (XmlNode XMLNode in XMLNodes)
{
   //This will be found nicely
   string test1 = XMLNode["bag_LVC:identificatie"].InnerXml.ToString();
   //This will cause a NULL reference with or without a leading '//'
   string test2 = XMLNode["bag_LVC:gerelateerdeAdressen/bag_LVC:hoofdadres/bag_LVC:identificatie"].InnerXml.ToString();
   // This will get the element BUT it will only get the same
   // first element whatever node is procesed
   string xPathExpression = "//bag_LVC:gerelateerdeAdressen/bag_LVC:hoofdadres/bag_LVC:identificatie";
   XmlElement Hoofdadres = (XmlElement)XMLNode.SelectSingleNode(xPathExpression, ns);
}
```

Does anyone know how to get the correct value of the `hoofdadres\identificatie` element of each node.

Example XML:

```
     <xb:antwoord>
      <xb:producten>
      <product_LVC:LVC-product>
        <bag_LVC:Standplaats>
          <bag_LVC:gerelateerdeAdressen>
            <bag_LVC:hoofdadres>
              <bag_LVC:identificatie>1883200000020771</bag_LVC:identificatie> 
            </bag_LVC:hoofdadres>
           </bag_LVC:gerelateerdeAdressen>
         <bag_LVC:identificatie>1883030000000010</bag_LVC:identificatie> 
       </bag_LVC:Standplaats>

       <bag_LVC:Standplaats>
          <bag_LVC:gerelateerdeAdressen>
            <bag_LVC:hoofdadres>
              <bag_LVC:identificatie>1883200000015663</bag_LVC:identificatie> 
            </bag_LVC:hoofdadres>
          </bag_LVC:gerelateerdeAdressen>
        <bag_LVC:identificatie>1883030000000011</bag_LVC:identificatie> 
       </bag_LVC:Standplaats>
       </product_LVC:LVC-product>
       </xb:producten>
       </xb:antwoord>
```

**Update**

When I use `//*:hoofdadres/*:identificatie` then I got an exception

```
//*:hoofdadres/*:identificatie' has an invalid token.
```

It's the part that troubles me:

```
// This will get the element BUT it will only get the same
// first element whatever node is processed
string xPathExpression = "//bag_LVC:gerelateerdeAdressen/bag_LVC:hoofdadres/bag_LVC:identificatie";
XmlElement Hoofdadres = (XmlElement)XMLNode.SelectSingleNode(xPathExpression, ns);
```

Answer (score 0):

in pure xquery:

```
doc()//\*:hoofdadres/\*:identificatie
```